# Anaconda installation get stuck at extract: anaconda-2020.02-py37_0.tar.bz2?

Tags: python, anaconda3

I am new to python. I am installing Anaconda 3 2020.02 (64-bit) on my windows 7 laptop. It get stuck at file name as anaconda-2020.02-py37_tar.bz2 
I tried multiple time but it's happening everytime

Comment: Have you tried extracting the tar.bz2 file with 7zip?

Comment: How do I extract it ? I am using installer which is getting stuck at this particular file. Are you suggesting to download it separately?

Comment: somehow it worked !!!

Comment: How did you extract it? I got the same problem

Answer (score 6):

I just did it. It does not get stuck, it just takes a veeeeery long time to extract (like 10-15 mins). the final size of the Anaconda folder is 5.4 GB, that is probably the reason why.

Comment: They really need a better progress indicator in that case.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem. I tried to install an previous version of anaconda from
https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/
It downloaded and installed "Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe" and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue as well on my Windows 10 desktop. All I see is lots of idle conda processes in Task Manager and the installer stuck on anaconda-2020.02-py37_0.tar.bz2. Extracting the anaconda-2020.02-py37_0.tar.bz2 file with 7zip while the installer was stuck did not help.

I solved the problem by running the installer on a separate Windows 10 machine which does not have trouble running the installer. I then moved the `Anaconda3` installation folder to my problematic machine.

Now this does not normally work and anaconda highly recommends installing by running the installer instead of transplanting the folder. But we can hack it to work (as far as I have tested) by doing the following:

1) Using a program, search through every text file (.cmake, .txt, .sh, ..py, .pc, .prl, .conf) for string instances of the old full path to `Anaconda3` on the original installation directory and replace them with the full path to the new `Anaconda3` installation directory.
Some paths may use  double backslash `\\`, single backslash `\`, forward slash `/` 
or even a mix of them. Be careful to handle all these cases.

2) Some numpy related text files may contain paths to `C:\Program Files(x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2020.X.XXX\...`. Be sure to change this path to the available intel accelerated libraries on the new machine.

Additionally, copy over the start menu program shortcuts (found in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3(64 bit)`) to the same location on the new machine. Right click on each shortcut file to change the target path.

If the transplanting worked, on the problematic machine you should be able to launch Anaconda prompt from the Start Menu, launch spyder, and subsequently run numpy functions.

This is a hackish solution. But until we can find the root cause of the installation issue this is the only way I can install Anaconda-2020.02. I am waiting to see if there are better ways to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for a while and just tried @wizu recommendation. It worked. I was able to install Anaconda3 2019.10 successfully. I think this is specifically a issue with the 2020.02 release.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a bunch of posts of this without any great solutions. I had the error message about the failed package extracts on the latest version of Anaconda as of Oct 31, 2023. I tried "retry" a bunch of times, but it still failed. I also tried canceling and re-starting, but that didn't help either. One other user, @Borisl, suggested that the path might be too long. I am not able to change my path, so I don't have a lot of options.

I just ignored the error and continued on with the installation. I was still able to create new environment using the Anaconda Prompt for Spyder, and Spyder launched correctly and imported Pandas.

I think until Anaconda releases a new distribution or advice on how to deal with this, we can just keep calm and carry on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, 3y 6m after the OP's question.

The problem was that I was trying to install conda **to a path that is too long** for the installer. Unfortunately it does not error out with "path too long", but with "failed to extract". I find this quite misleading an error message.

Anyway, the solution was to **install to a shorter path**.

Posting an answer so that others find a solution more easily in the future.