# anaconda installation on windows 10 gets stuck when extracting anaconda-2020.02-py37_0.tar.bz2

Tags: windows, installation, anaconda, windows-10, failed-installation

I am installing anaconda 2020.02 on a windows 10 machine. Everything runs smoothly until the installation gets stuck at:

**Extract anaconda-2020.02-py37_0.tar.bz2**
[image: screenshot here].

I have tried the installation several times (removing all files relating to the installation every time) and the same thing happens always.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

---

This question was asked 5 days ago by someone else but no explicit solution was given:

[Anaconda installation get stuck at extract: anaconda-2020.02-py37_0.tar.bz2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60915224/anaconda-installation-get-stuck-at-extract-anaconda-2020-02-py37-0-tar-bz2)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My installer was stuck for hours at a time. So, I went to Anaconda's repo https://repo.continuum.io/archive/ and installed the immediately previous version 2019.10 and it installed just fine.